# GridSearchCV instance is not fitted yet. Call 'fit' with appropriate arguments before using this estimator

Tags: python, scikit-learn, sklearn-pandas, roc

I am doing a course in coursera and need to submit this last assignment in order to pass. However, I am unable to complete it. I encounter **NotFittedError** in **line 16** of the code. Can someone help me to find what is wrong with this code.

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split, GridSearchCV
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.metrics import roc_curve, auc

def engagement_model():
    train = pd.read_csv('assets/train.csv')
    train_X = train[train.columns[1:9]]
    train_y = train.iloc[:, 9:]
    test = pd.read_csv('assets/test.csv')
    
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(train_X, train_y)
    class_rf=RandomForestClassifier()
    grid_values = {'n_estimators':[10,100], 'max_depth': [None, 30]}
    grid_clf_auc = GridSearchCV(class_rf, param_grid=grid_values, scoring='roc_auc_score')
    predict_test = grid_clf_auc.predict_proba(test[test.columns[1:9]])
    predict_test = predict_test[:,1]
    
    return pd.series(predict_test, index=[test['id']])
    
engagement_model()
```

The error I am getting is

```
NotFittedError: This GridSearchCV instance is not fitted yet. Call 'fit' with appropriate arguments before using this estimator.
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [RandomForestClassifier instance not fitted yet. Call 'fit' with appropriate arguments before using this method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51397611/randomforestclassifier-instance-not-fitted-yet-call-fit-with-appropriate-argu)

Comment: @Arpit Did my answer help you? If so, I'd appreciate [if you accept it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/1133249)

Answer (score 0):

You are getting an error because you didn't fit the model. You need first to fit it on your train data and then you can predict on the test data. Use .fit() method on your grid_clf_auc

Answer (score 0):

Before calling `grid_clf_auc.predict_proba`, you need to call `grid_clf_auc.fit(train_X, train_y)`. Otherwise you just have created a `GradSearchCV` object but you have not fitted it to your data. A classifier not fittet to your data cannot make a prediction.