# NotFittedError: This RandomForestRegressor instance is not fitted yet. Call 'fit' with appropriate arguments before using this estimator

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, random-forest

I have taken a look at this: [RandomForestClassifier instance not fitted yet. Call 'fit' with appropriate arguments before using this method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51397611/randomforestclassifier-instance-not-fitted-yet-call-fit-with-appropriate-argu) not helped.

I was running RandomForest Regressor model with RandomizedSearchCV. It was running for 3 hr and suddenly it gave this error.

The relevant part of my code:

```
rf = RandomForestRegressor()
rs_rf = RandomizedSearchCV(rf, param, cv=2, n_jobs=-1, verbose=1)
rs_rf.fit(X_train, Y_train)
rs_rf_train = rf.predict(X_train)
rs_rf_test = rf.predict(X_test)
```

The error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NotFittedError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-de03d0ce1f81> in <cell line: 141>()
    139 rs_rf = RandomizedSearchCV(rf, param, cv=2, n_jobs=-1, verbose=1)
    140 rs_rf.fit(X_train, Y_train)
--> 141 rs_rf_train = rf.predict(X_train)
    142 rs_rf_test = rf.predict(X_test)
    143 

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py in check_is_fitted(estimator, attributes, msg, all_or_any)
   1388 
   1389     if not fitted:
-> 1390         raise NotFittedError(msg % {"name": type(estimator).__name__})
   1391 
   1392 

NotFittedError: This RandomForestRegressor instance is not fitted yet. Call 'fit' with appropriate arguments before using this estimator.
```

Comment: Correction, you fitted rs_rf and then you are using rf to predict, which is not the one you fitted.

Comment: I see what you mean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You pass the `RandomForestRegressor` instance to the `RandomizedSearchCV` instance.

When fitting the `RandomizedSearchCV`, you actually fit multiple RFR and cross-validate them. Your `rs_rf` instance then is the result of the `RandomizedSearchCV`, which contains one or more fitted `RandomForestRegressor`s. You can access the best of these by calling `best_rf = rs_rf.best_estimator_`

When you call the `rf` object, you call an unfitted instance, because it has been passed to `RandomizedSearchCV`, which in turn has been fit, not `RandomForestRegressor`.

I hope this explanation makes it clearer for you.